# Nested match_recognize query not supported in flink SQL?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, match-recognize

I am using flink 1.11 and trying nested query where match_recognize is inside, as shown below :

```
select * from events where id = (SELECT * FROM events MATCH_RECOGNIZE (PARTITION BY org_id ORDER BY proctime MEASURES A.id AS startId ONE ROW PER MATCH PATTERN (A C* B) DEFINE A AS A.tag = 'tag1', C AS C.tag <> 'tag2', B AS B.tag = 'tag2'));
```

And I am getting an error as : `org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table 'A' not found`

Is this not supported ? If not what's the alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get something working by doing this:

```java
Table events = tableEnv.fromDataStream(input,
    $("sensorId"),
    $("ts").rowtime(),
    $("kwh"));

tableEnv.createTemporaryView("events", events);

Table matches = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
                "SELECT id " +
                    "FROM events " +
                    "MATCH_RECOGNIZE ( " +
                        "PARTITION BY sensorId " +
                        "ORDER BY ts " +
                        "MEASURES " +
                            "this_step.sensorId AS id " +
                        "AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW " +
                        "PATTERN (this_step next_step) " +
                        "DEFINE " +
                            "this_step AS TRUE, " +
                            "next_step AS TRUE " +
                    ")"
        );

tableEnv.createTemporaryView("mmm", matches);

Table results = tableEnv.sqlQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM events WHERE events.sensorId IN (select * from mmm)");

tableEnv
    .toAppendStream(results, Row.class)
    .print();
```

For some reason, I couldn't get it to work without defining a view. I kept getting Calcite errors.

I guess you are trying to avoid enumerating all of the columns from A in the MEASURES clause of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE. You may want to compare the resulting execution plans to see if there's any significant difference.

Comment: Both of these approaches did not work. 
In the first case I got the same exception as mentioned in the quesiton.
In the second case I got a new exception : org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table 'm' not found
Can you help me with a concrete example may be ?

Comment: See my updated answer for a concrete example.

Comment: Note that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20077 may prevent you from using this approach with Flink 1.11.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the explanation. That approach works for me.